# Why is there an error about headers and authorization in a Stripe dependency?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, stripe-payments

Stripe HTTP request dependency returns an error about headers, but these are not configurable.

Using a GET request seems fine, but a post route fails with the error:

`error [err_invalid_char]: invalid character in header content ["authorization"]`

```
app.post('/charge',function(req,res){

  stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 10,
      description: 'Charge',
      currency: 'gbp',
      customer: 'cus_EXgisfTr7LuiO9'
  },function(err,result){
    if(err){
      res.status(400);
      res.send(err);
    }
    else{
      res.status(201);
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Hitting the endpoint https://myapp.herokuapp.com/charge with an HTTP POST request returns this to the console:

`error [err_invalid_char]: invalid character in header content ["authorization"]`

This is a Stripe dependency however and not configured by the developer.

Comment: The `Authorization` header is where your Secret API key `sk_test_123` is sent. My guess is that the value you're setting when loading/initializing Stripe has an invalid character. Try hardcoding it straight in your code to confirm

Comment: @koopajah You're exactly correctly. Was using dotenv and the invalid character must have been '.' in process.env.STRIPESECRET. 

So this is the solution - Excellent thank you. 

I wonder why environmental variables aren't correctly translated in this instance?

I really struggled to analyse this one out, I guess it was obvious in the end that it had to do with the authorization key - Thanks for your help.

Comment: This saved me a bit of time. Someone might want to answer this.

Comment: Thanks for that @koopajah. I faced an error when passing the wrong secret key.

Answer (score 0):

The above error occurs when the Stripe Secret API key is passed incorrectly.
Just for the help,

```
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe(env.STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY);
```

make sure you change the key as per the production/development environment.
Cheers.